# Converting UIImage to NSData using UIImagePNGRepresentation yields different results on simulator vs. on actual device

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

I have a piece of code that downloads a PNG image from a server into a `UIImage` object, then verifies the correctness of the image by converting it into `NSData`, hashing the contents of `NSData`, and comparing the result to a known value.

In pseudo code, I'm doing the following:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsofURL:<some url>]];
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
int dataLength = [imageData length];
... some hashing follows
```

When I run this code in iPad 4.2 Simulator and then on an actual iPad device, sometimes I get different values for 'dataLength' and, hence, my hashing produces a different value on the simulator as opposed to the device.

For example, I have one TestImage1.png that has the length of 38084 bytes on both the device and the simulator, but then I have a smaller image TestImage2.png that has the length of 9710 bytes on the device but 9751 bytes on the simulator (ie. 41 bytes more!).

Is there a different, consistent way for me to take an arbitrary `UIImage` object and convert it into a stream of bytes such that this stream will be identical on both the simulator and the device?

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation() indeed can produce slightly different results between the simulator and the actual device. To solve this problem, I ended up using raw NSData and not going through UIImage at all.

In the original problem I had two scenarios to handle:

 (1) Read an image from disk.
 (2) Read an image from URL.
In both cases, I had the option of reading the bits directly into NSData, bypassing UIImage entirely, and calculating my hashes on the data itself.

This solved the inconsistency problem.

Comment: Then you should answer your own question.